# Monitor system logins and queries history in the database

Tags: sql-server, logging

I am authorized to access 1 database X on 1 server A with full rights on this database (same as administrator of database X). I want to monitor the history of all access and queries on database X (only database X, not server). I have tried to find ways but all are access and query management on the server. I don't have admin rights on the server so I can't do this. Is there any possible solution for this? Please share if any!
Many thanks!

Comment: What does "*all access*" mean?...please be *very* specific. For example, if someone logs in and connects to database `X` but they don't run any queries, do you want to know? What information do you want to know?... assumptively the timestamp, the user, and the action / query?

Comment: @J.D. Yes. I want to know the connection time to database X (even when just connecting without performing any action)/query, user connect/query, query statement content if any.

Comment: Can you execute the below command ? :
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions

Comment: No. I don't have right